# WPF: Data binding & Display member path

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

i have created a `RibbonGallery/ComboBox` to display a list of installed fonts.

[image]

but sometimes after entering say "V" this is what i get

[image]

look at the text in the menu.

```
[Font Family: Name=...
```

why is that happening.

**code**

```
// xaml
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox Label="Gallery">
    <ribbon:RibbonGallery SelectedValue="ABC" SelectedValuePath="Content" MaxColumnCount="1">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory x:Name="fontsMenu" />
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>

// code behind
InstalledFontCollection col = new InstalledFontCollection();
fontsMenu.ItemsSource = col.Families;
fontsMenu.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

Comment: Did you try setting the SelectedValuePath to Name?

Comment: Is there a font starting with 'V' in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how FontFamily.ToString() implemented and thats exactly what we have displayed:

```
  public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "[{0}: Name={1}]", new object[] {  base.GetType().Name, this.Name });
    }
```

You definitely need to set some DisplayMemberPath to "Name" and you already have one on RibbonGalleryCategory but now i'm curious - shouldnt it be set on RibbonGallery or even RibbonComboBox? Frankly speaking i haven't used wpf ribbon controls yet - all i can suggest is just assumption.

Hope this'll help :)